# Any chance to update a UIProgressView while NSKeyedUnarchiver?

Tags: ios, time, uiprogressview, nskeyedunarchiver

in my app, I save arrays in core data with `NSKeyedArchiver`.
Then, I use the following code when the data is needed (to feed Core Plot) :

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.myqueue", 0);
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
    dataForPlot = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:self.measure.dataArray];
});
```

This works great ! But when the dataArray is big it can't take a few seconds to unarchive.
Is there any way update a progressView bar while unarchiving ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a delegate for you : NSKeyedUnarchiverDelegate , but I don't know if it will help to update the UIProcessView.

Why not show a UIActivityIndicatorView instead of UIProcessView.

Comment: Thanks for the delegate but it didn't help, unfortunately. I think that a UIProgressView is better than a UIActivityIndicatorView for impatient users ;).

Comment: You are right, but I didn't find any solution about that...

Comment: I think there's no easy way to do it...Thanks for your help!